# How Do I Check if Server.GetLastError() = System.Web.UI.ViewStateException?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception, viewstate

I'm trying to do something along the lines of the following:

```
If Server.GetLastError() = System.Web.UI.ViewStateException Then
    '   Do something here
End If
```

But this isn't working and gives me this: 'ViewStateException' is a type class and cannot be used in an expression.

So I've tried variations of this:

```
If (Server.GetLastError.GetType = TypeOf (System.Web.UI.ViewStateException)) Then
```

But that's not working either.

What am I missing?

Comment: what's not working in the second case? try `if(TypeOf Server.GetLastError Is System.Web.UI.ViewStateException)`

Comment: Same but with addition of "is operator does not accept operands of type boolean" and if I change it to = instead then I just get the same original error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your syntax. Use the [TypeOf Operator (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx)

```
Dim lastError As Exception = Server.GetLastError().InnerException
If TypeOf lastError Is System.Web.UI.ViewStateException Then
    '   Do something here
End If
```

Or you can try to cast to the type you want and check if it is not nothing.

```
Dim lastError = TryCast(Server.GetLastError().InnerException, System.Web.UI.ViewStateException)
If lastError IsNot Nothing Then
    '   Do something here
End If
```

Comment: That still gives me "'ViewStateException' is a type class and cannot be used in an expression."

Comment: My apologies @Nkosi the second part does work. Now I'm just getting HttpUnhandledException instead of ViewStateException so need to work out how to check that.

Comment: Just realized I had left out the `TypeOf` operator in the first part of my answer. sorry.

Comment: The `HttpUnhandledException` occurs when an error happens in your controller action that was thrown and not handled by user code.

Comment: I've got it working with the following change: Dim lastError = TryCast(Server.GetLastError.InnerException(), System.Web.UI.ViewStateException)

Comment: Glad you got it working. Do you need me to update my answer?

Comment: Yeah if you don't mind, it might help someone else that may be looking for this.